# SSRS add group to existing rdl file

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2015, grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

For an SSRS report (Visual Studio 2015), how does one add a group (for visual effect) to an existing rdl file?  I already have "group by" in my .SQL query, but I am referring to a tablix group?  [My underlying SQL system that the SSRS gets data from is 2008 r2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have a tablix or a matrix on your RDL.. it's as simple as right clicking on your details line and adding a group.. many ways to skin a cat.. bottom of designer you will have the Row Group and Column Group windows.. you can add / create Groups there as well.. same thing